# Assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just upgraded from Rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0.

Now I got this error:

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Here's the relevant part of my controller action:

```
# app/models/users_controller.rb
def create_user
  @user = User.new()
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

How can I solve this?

There are similar problems posted here on SO, byt my problem is different to the posted ones, because the hints which were given there aren't a solution.

Comment: What does your `params[:user]` contain?

Comment: First there are [some other question at Stackoverflow with the same error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=When+assigning+attributes%2C+you+must+pass+a+hash+as+an+argument+is%3Aquestion). Second, your question would be more valuable to other if the exception message were included in _text form_ in your text. Voting for close (duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398020/when-assigning-attributes-you-must-pass-a-hash-as-an-argument)

Comment: My params[:user] is empty at the moment

Comment: @Felix: So do I understand it correctly that you want to allow `params[:user]` to be empty without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow `params[:user]` to be passed in empty, you can do this to prevent throwing an exception:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user]) unless params[:user].blank?
```

However, this might be a strange behaviour, since the controller action is meant to create a `User`.

In Rails, there is also a method [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F), that is the inverse of [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F). You can use whichever one is more legible to you.

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user]) if params[:user].present?
```