# Not updating attribute in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have creating a web application using Ruby on Rails but now I'm troubling a issue which is post updating, I'm trying to solve this issue which followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944871/actioncontrollerparametermissing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-film) also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398020/when-assigning-attributes-you-must-pass-a-hash-as-an-argument). Below is my code:

```
 def update
  @edit = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  params.permit!
  if @edit.update_attributes(params[:post])
      redirect_to home_path
      flash[:notice] = "Your post updated"
  else
     flash[:notice] = "Wrong"
  end
end
```

When I use this code then showing

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

After that

```
def update
  @edit = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  params.permit!
  if @edit.update_attributes(update_params)
      redirect_to home_path
      flash[:notice] = "Your post updated"
  else
     flash[:notice] = "Wrong"
  end
end

private
def update_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :details, :summery)
end
```

When I use this then showing

> param is missing or the value is empty: post

Where is my actual fault?

Comment: If you get `param is missing or the value is empty: post` I believe that problem is in your form which doesn't submit post attributes as your controller expect it.

Comment: All attributes are showing properly from existing but when I click submit then showing error

Answer (score 0):

It's your form that is causing this error.  It means that you aren't passing the values nested inside  `post`.  If you view your `params` (raise `params.inspect`) you'll be able to see that `post` doesn't exist.

If you use `form_for` (or `simple_form` or `formtastic`) this is handled for you, but if you are using `form_tag` or manually creating a form with `HTML`, or submitting data via ajax you need to add this.

In ajax, you can add by serializing the data before submitting - in a `form_tag` you can do it this way:

```
form_tag post_path(@post)
```

Comment: My form is `<%= form_for :edit, url: update_path(:post_id => @edit.post_id), action: :update, method:  :put, remote: true  do |f| %>`

Comment: Why not just assign the post to @post, and then use `form_form @post, remote: true do |f|` -- If it's an updatable object, rails automatically knows that and will use put (or patch if needed, but you don't ahve to worry about that)